# Very small package for apt-get experimentation?

Tags: apt, package-management

I spent a lot of time this weekend installing and uninstalling *kmines* to test out options on `apt-get install`, subshells, and the like. Is there a very small, simple package--perhaps with no manpages--that is good for quick demo installations and purges? Minimizing installation and purge time is the goal.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

rolldice 
it has man pages but just takes a couple seconds to install and purge.